# Custom rounding logic in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding

Hi everyone i am trying to create a custom logic for rounding off a decimal as specified in the rules.

The rule states that any decimal whose value is in between .01 to .05 should have .05 value. Any value which falls between .06 to .09 should be equal to .10.

For example

```
1.05 => 1.05
1.84 => 1.85
1.06 => 1.10
1.79 => 1.80
```

I tried to play with the formula specified in oracle website [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROUND-number.html#GUID-849F6C45-0D72-4464-9C0F-8B6822BA85E1). But it didn't work see below code

```
select 
round(1.05 * power(10,2) + .05) * power(10,-2) as Rounding1
, round(1.84 * power(10,2) + .05) * power(10,-2) as Rounding2
, round(1.06 * power(10,2) + .05) * power(10,-2) as Rounding3
, round(1.79 * power(10,2) + .05) * power(10,-2) as Rounding4
from dual;
```

Any ideas on how this can be implemented?

Comment: `ceil(value*20)/20` suffices your requirements

Comment: thanks wolf could have voted on your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this logic does what you want:

```
select ceil(num * 20) / 20 from tablename
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, yes it worked similar to Wolfrevokcats answer. How did you know you will divide it by 20?

Comment: @dimas . . . Because the second decimal place can take on two values (2 * 10 for the first decimal place).  I hadn't seen the comment; I was trying to test the code to be sure it worked for your cases.

Comment: yes tried to test it against different scenarios and seems to be working fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks. And i have a doubt we can use round function right. Both will give the same value right ?

Comment: @AravindhanR . . . You can try it.  It might be subtly different.